# My application is not working on AMD CPUs

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, hardware

I have created a Winforms application in .NET Framework 2.0 in Visual Studio 2005 in C#.

The application uses the following references on x64:

**MS Visual Studio C++ 2005 Redistributable (x64)**

**MS Visual Studio C++ 2005 Redistributable**

and for X86

**MS Visual Studio C++ 2005 Redistributable**

for Crystal Reports. The references are inside the setup.exe.

I tried to install the app on a PC with AMD processor and Windows 10, but the application (splashscreen) does not even start.

My first form is a simple SpashScreen:

```
private void DoSplash()
{
            SplashScreen sp = new SplashScreen();
            Application.Run(sp);
}
public Main()
{
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeComponent2();
            ...
            Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoSplash));
            th.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            th.Abort();
            ...
            //checking for new update
}
```

[image: Build screenshot tab in VS 2005]
[image: Solution screenshot tab in VS 2005]

Do I need to change something in Visual Studio ?

Comment: `Abort()` is a really really bad idea, and doesn't work at all on newer frameworks. I suggest you find another way of timing an event. Unlikely this has got anything to do with AMD processors as opposed to Intel.

Comment: I would start by checking Event viewer if anything is logged why the app doesn't start. It's probably some dependency missing

Comment: What are you using the C++ runtime for? It's a C# application. And why are you using such an old compiler?

Comment: To fix it , you probably need to install the .Net 3.5 runtime. From Control Panel->Add or remove programs->Additional Windows features.